# trigger to update specific column when insert/update happened in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I trying to write a trigger that will update a column when user insert or updates a row, within the same table.
Example:
insert into user(ID, F_NM, L_NM, EMAIL) values ('1', 'John','Doe','john.doe@market.org.com');
after the insert, i want to call: update user set ORG = 'market' where ID = '1'.

```
create or replace trigger user_change
after insert or update of EMAIL on USER
for each row
declare
  NEW_ORG VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
  CASE
    when :NEW.EMAIL like '$@market.org.com' then
      NEW_ORG := 'market';
    ........
  END CASE;

  UPDATE USER set ORG = NEW_ORG where ID = :NEW.ID
END;
```

Calculating the new ORG work, but I can't get the update statement to work.
I get 'ORA-04091 table USER is mutating, trigger/funtion may not see it', figure its due to me inserting/updating the same record at same time. Tried adding 'pragma autonomous_transaction' and 'commit' to the trigger, the insert/update of fields works but the ORG does not get updated.

Also tried changing to INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OF EMAIL but I keep getting 'ORA-04073 column list not valid for this trigger type'

```
create or replace trigger user_change
instead of insert or update of EMAIL on USER
```

while i get 'ORA-25002 cannot create instead of triggers on tables'

```
create or replace trigger user_change
instead of insert on USER
```

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply turn the trigger to a *before* trigger, when you can set the value before it is written? This way, you don't need to run a new DML statement on the table, which avoid the "mutating" error.

```
create or replace trigger user_change
after insert or update of email on user
for each row
begin
    if :new.email like '%@market.org.com' then
        :new.org := 'market';
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: @HangLin: the trigger sets the value of `org` in pseudo-table `:new` *before* it is inserted or updated. Then the modified value is inserted or updated to the table with the rest of the data.

Comment: thank you so much, i've been on this for the last 3 hours. Did not know that I can modify the original data within the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `org` column can be calculated virtual column. In this case it would be better to create user-defined deterministic pl/sql function that returns correct calculated value and add it to your table, for example:

```sql
Alter table t add org varchar2(30) generated always as (f_get_org(email))
```